# wordpress contact form-7 attachment issue

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I am not getting attachment in my contact form-7 in live site while at same time it's working fine on my production.

I am sure there is no right permission issue on server as i tried upoading some file on it.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the attachment larger than 2 MiB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure SMTP on your server